# Paste two vectors and reshape with one group per row

Tags: r

I want to transform a data frame to a different format. An example would like as follows:

```
    value        index
1   0.10         18
2   0.14          5   
3   0.14         40   
4   0.14         28   
5   0.14         29   
6   0.14         46   
7   0.14         13   
8   0.17         10   
9   0.17         35   
10  0.17         38
```

Transform to:

```
#Basically, each row has 5 groups of numbers. Each group has two numbers. 
#First number in a group is from the second column
#Second number in a group is from the first column
#So, the end dataframe will have 2 rows each with 10 columns

18 0.1     5  0.14     40 0.14     28 0.14     29 0.14 
46 0.14    13 0.14     10 0.17     35 0.17     38 0.17
```

In C, I could use a for loop as follows to do that

```
for (i=1; i<num_rows; i *=5) {
   //set values for each row 
}
```

However, I couldn't find similar syntax in R. I might be thinking the solution in a wrong direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can paste together the two columns using the `paste` function and then add them to a matrix with five elements in each row with the `matrix` function:

```
matrix(paste(dat$index, dat$value), ncol=5, byrow=TRUE)
#      [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4]      [,5]     
# [1,] "18 0.1"  "5 0.14"  "40 0.14" "28 0.14" "29 0.14"
# [2,] "46 0.14" "13 0.14" "10 0.17" "35 0.17" "38 0.17"
```

If instead of pasting them you wanted to have each value in a separate column, you could use:

```
matrix(rbind(dat$index, dat$value), ncol=10, byrow=TRUE)
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
# [1,]   18 0.10    5 0.14   40 0.14   28 0.14   29  0.14
# [2,]   46 0.14   13 0.14   10 0.17   35 0.17   38  0.17
```